# drupal mysql connection issue

Tags: database, drupal

I am working on drupal project, somehow this error popped out and I have no clue please let me know if anyone knows about this

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in lock_may_be_available()`

I haven't changed anything, I tried to fetch database using normal query writing in PHP its working fine but when I am trying to fetch my site this error coming up. I also tried restarting Sql and Apache server.

if anyone knows how to fix this please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Ali

Comment: try removing this file /tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: I did that but its still not working, when I restarted mysql  it creates mysql.sock file automatically

Comment: yes it will create the file automatically

Comment: But its not working I am getting the same error 'PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in lock_may_be_available()'

Comment: maybe this can help https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2011-02-08/what-does-this-error-mean

Comment: Or maybe this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2110549

Comment: Or this: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28690168/Linux-5-Drupal-7-PDOException-SQLSTATE-HY000-2002-Can't-connect-to-local-MySQL-server-through-socket.html

It may happen that database become too big and there is no more free disk space.